# Damaged wire inside fireplace insert, New construction

Tags: fire-hazard

Due to a previous house fire am I being to pick about exposed wire isolation due to staple?

First off, the county inspector came out on July 29, 2020 an failed the inspection with five items.  One item being fire place not wired and installed!

The next  day we get a call from GC to unlock house for inspector to come back to check fix items. Around eleven o’clock we get a text from GC saying it had passed but  no one from the inspectors office came back out. They passed it off of pictures the GC had sent earlier that morning.

Should I be concerned with this being inside the fireplace cavity where if can be exposed to excess heat?

What would be the proper way to fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: that looks more like tugging on the wire after being secured. Sheathing should not be broken and exposed. A new cable is always preferred but if that is just the ground exposed, then electrical tape would work

Comment: @noybman, make that your answer, It is what I have seen done, as long as the insulation of the other wires are intact

Comment: Please explain more fully as I have never seen exposed combustibles (wood, romex, etc.) "inside the fireplace cavity where it can be exposed to excess heat". Where exactly is that picture from?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Perhaps it is a disposable fireplace.

Comment: Yes Jimmy, it’s inside a fake rock fireplace with a electric or gas insert.